# Use custom function inside eloquent orderBy() method

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I have a list or products in my database that needs to be ordered based on their `updated_at` field. But I also want to view the products at the beginning that are missing some attributes.

For example, I want to list those products at first that are missing description or colors and then order them based on their update date. Also I want to paginate them so I cannot sort them after I retrieve all the products from database.

So is there a way to achieve this using eloquent in Laravel?

This is how my `products` table looks like,

```
products
    -id
    -style
    -title
    -description
    -colors
    -sizes
    -cost
    -weight
    -created_at
    -updated_at
```

Comment: can you show schema of products   table..?

Comment: @DCoder I have updated my question with my products talbe

Answer (score 0):

You can use limit and skip for pagination not sure  but you can use like this for your problem..

```
function getProdcucts($skip, $limit){
           $list = DB::table('reports')->select()
                          ->where('colors', '=', null)
                          ->orWhere('description', '=', null)
                          ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
                          ->skip($skip)
                          ->limit($limit)
                          ->get();
           return $list;
      }
```

Dont fetch all  record in one time, fetch record from db according to per page items.

Comment: This will limit my list to only those products that are missing `colors` or `description`. But I only want them to be listed at the beginning and also list the products that have all data, ordered by `updated_at`.

Comment: simple bro write a second eloquent to get all product then do union of both result may be this can help you..

Comment: Don't you think that's too much? If I wanted to get all products then I would have run the custom sorting to results instead of running two eloquent queries and `union` them.